# .htaccess forcefully hide home page uri

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ subpage [L]
```

So basically if someone visit "www.example.com," he'll see the content of "www.example.com/subpage" without the url changed. This is good.

However, they can still visit the page by "www.example.com/subpage." If that happens, I want the url changed back to "www.example.com."

Is it possible? What I've tried so far gave me redirection loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional rule that matches against the actual request and not the URI. Since the rewrite engine loops, the URI keeps changing, so you need to match against the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable. You need this rule **before** the rule that you have in your question:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+subpage(\?|\ |$)
RewriteRule ^ / [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Would you please explain this line and its regex: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+subpage(\?|\ |$)

Comment: @Shawn the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable is the first line of the HTTP request, so it looks something like: `GET /request HTTP/1.1`. The regex matches the first space, then the `/` (there could be more than one) and then the "subpage", followed by either a `?` (query string), a space or the end of the request.